# onChangeText for info inside dynamic array in React Native with this.state.maps

Tags: react-native, dynamic-arrays

This is my state and I'm trying to change who inside info.

```
state = {
     info: [
          {
              who:'Player 1',                
           },
          {
              who:'Player 2',             
           },
        ]
   }
```

When I try to do the onChangeText. I'm trying to make 'who' into whatever name the user would input and I'm unsure of how to do it.

```
{this.state.info.map((e) => (
     <View style={styles.buttons}>
          <TextInput style={styles.txt}
                 onChangeText={(e.who) => this.setState({e.who})}
          />
          value={e.who}
     </View>
))}
```

Comment: Right now your implementation is wrong. Please read this https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, i used functional-component

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([
    {
      who: 'Player 1',
    },
  ]);
const [texts, setText] = useState('');

return (
  {info.map((e, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <Text>{e.who}</Text>
    </View>
  ))}
  <TextInput onChangeText={setText} value={texts} />
  <Button
    title="input"
    onPress={() => {
      setInfo([...info, { who: texts }]);
      setText('');
    }}
  />
)
```